# ReadAllLines for a Stream object?

Tags: c#, file, text, stream

There exists a `File.ReadAllLines` but not a `Stream.ReadAllLines`.

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Test_Resources.Resources.Accounts.txt"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    // Would prefer string[] result = reader.ReadAllLines();
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Does there exist a way to do this or do I have to manually loop through the file line by line?

Comment: How about `reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` ?

Comment: @LB, I was considering the same. But it seems awfully inefficient.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can write a method which reads line by line, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Func<Stream> streamProvider,
                                     Encoding encoding)
{
    using (var stream = streamProvider())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it as:

```
var lines = ReadLines(() => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                    .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName),
                      Encoding.UTF8)
                .ToList();
```

The `Func<>` part is to cope when reading more than once, and to avoid leaving streams open unnecessarily. You could easily wrap that code up in a method, of course.

If you don't need it all in memory at once, you don't even need the `ToList`...

Comment: Do you need to check !reader.EndOfStream as well or is that not necessary?

Comment: @CodeBlend: No, `ReadLine` returns `null` when it reaches the end of the stream.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there any advantage to checking `.ReadLine() != null`, rather than `!reader.EndOfStream`? It seems like the latter makes the `while` loop much neater and easier to read (see Bryan Johnson's formulation below)? (especially when combined with `yield return`, since you then no longer need the `line` variable at all?)

Comment: I would propose an edit, but editing a @JonSkeet answer seems ... idk ... sacrilegious ;)

Comment: @Brondahl: Yes, there's a benefit: you may not know whether the stream has ended until you try to read from it. There may be no more data to come, which is what you actually care about. (An edit here would have been inappropriate - edits shouldn't change the intention, which this one certainly would have done.) (I suspect there may be cases where `StreamReader.EndOfStream` will basically give the wrong result here, but I'm not going to spend time trying to prove it right now.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think this is getting to the part of Streams that I've never really needed to understand since I've only ever used them with Files or WebRequests. If I've understood you correctly, then you're saying that there are ways of loading data into a Stream such that `.EndOfStream` could return `false`, but calling `.ReadLine()` would still return `null`. Is that right?

Is the opposite also possible? That `.EndOfStream` could return `true`, but calling `.ReadLine()` would return actual data?

Comment: @Brondahl: Yes, you've understood me correctly. The reverse should *not* be true, unless the stream is misbehaving.

Comment: `string line` should be changed to `string? line` since you want it to be able to hold `null` (C# 8.0+ feature)

Comment: @WENDYN: And then it would be invalid for anyone with nullable reference types turned off, or using an older compiler. Aside from anything else, I'm not going to revise nearly 20,000 answers every year when a new version of C# comes out, just to see whether new features are relevant. Anyone using NRTs should be aware of how to adapt non-NRT code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, well it's till there in C#11.0

Comment: @WENDYN: I don't understand your comment at all, or you didn't understand mine. When C# 11 comes out, do you think I should look through nearly 20,000 answers to see if any of them might take advantage of any of the new features? Or do you think that maybe it's reasonable for readers to take account of features introduced since an answer was posted?

Comment: I think new ppl might learn doing this as a bad habit

Comment: @WENDYN: If they've got nullable reference types enabled, they'll get a warning - they can address it. If they've *not* got nullable reference types enabled, the code is fine - whereas changing it to `string?` would create a warning that they may not even understand. I'm perfectly satisfied with my answer, and will *not* be changing it. If you want to make all your C# answers fail to compile for anyone with NRTs not enabled, that's fine - but I'm not going to.

Answer (score 49):

The `.EndOfStream` property can be used in the loop instead of checking if the next line is not null.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("example.txt"))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: See discussion on Jon Skeet's answer. Using `.EndOfStream` doesn't necessarily work for all Streams. I suspect it'll be fine for "simple" streams like Files and WebRequests, though.

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer**

Yes you have to loop line by line.

**Details**

Here the simplest approach. It is taken from `ReadAllLines`, [File.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs) > `InternalReadAllLines` > `ReadLine`, [StreamReader.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs).

You will see that the reference version handles all line terminator combinations: \r, \n, and \r\n correctly.

`ReadLine` does not return an extra empty string when the line terminator is \r\n, which is typical in DOS/Windows.

`ReadLine` also discards any text after the final delimiter.

```
public static String[] ReadAllLines(this TextReader reader)
{
    String line;
    
    List<String> lines = new List<String>();

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }

    return lines.ToArray();
}
```

While there are reasons to not use `ReadAllLines` at all, this is what the op asked.

This accepts a `TextReader`, not just a `StreamReader`. It supports a `StreamReader` or a `StringReader`.

BTW the name `StreamReader` is an abomination, since it does not read streams, but implements `TextReader` for files.
In contrast a Stream:
"Provides a generic view of a sequence of bytes. This is an abstract class." In other words it could be a FileStream -  binary stream with possibly no applicable text encoding.

**Why Use `ReadLine`**

Text files are post-fix delimited; meaning a new-line terminates each line.
Also there are 3 combinations for newlines in common use across Windows, Unix and Mac O/S. Your application may never be ported to another O/S, but it may be expected to read an external file from a foreign O/S.

`Split` is not equivalent to `ReadLine`. `Split` is suited best used for infix delimited strings, such as comma separated lists. It is unsuited for post-fix strings, where the delimiter may be one of three combinations. `Split` "sees" (parses) \r followed by \n as 2 separate delimiters and returns an empty string. It also returns any text after the final delimiter.

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option suggested in some other answers removes all empty lines, including those which were in the original input.

Thus for the input:

```
line1\r
\r
line3\r\n
```

`ReadLine` returns 3 lines. The 2nd is empty.
`Split` creates 4 strings. (There is an additional string after the last \n.) It then removes the 2nd and the 4th. This is not what `ReadAllLines` does.

Comment: I totally appreciate this answer, and agree it is correct.  But it isn't actually an answer. It's just a comment about someone elses answer.

Comment: @JohnHenckel I am sure I don't remember 8 years ago, but I am guessing SO blocked such a long comment. This was not the last time I was verbose and non-responsive to the OP. I should have been a lawyer, but I hate it when people do that to me :) I have edited my answer to actually answer the question, with code, before ranting on the use of `Split`

Answer (score 6):

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Test_Resources.Resources.Accounts.txt"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    // Would prefer string[] result = reader.ReadAllLines();
    string[] result = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines(this StreamReader reader)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible to get to your desired code:

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Test_Resources.Resources.Accounts.txt"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string[] result = reader.ReadAllLines().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use StreamReader then yes, you will have to use ReadLine and loop throught the StreamReader, reading line by line.

Something like that:

```
string line;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine(line); 
    }
}
```

or try

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {

       string[] content = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n","").Split('\t');
    }
```