# Reading line by line an inputstream

Tags: c#, file, stream

I have a website that posts a large file to my server. I need to read it line by line or at least be able to split it. It's 2000 pages long.

Right now, I have :

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    using (file.InputStream)
                    {
                       //Looking for this part
                    }
                }
```

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: use an `StreamReader` and read using `ReadLine()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed @Gusman's idea of using the streamreader.

```
stream = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);
using (stream)
{
    while (stream.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        var line =  stream.ReadLine();
        //some stuff              
    }
}
```

Thanks also @Ali

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Func<Stream> streamProvider,
                                     Encoding encoding)
{
    using (var stream = streamProvider())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

So :

```
var lines = ReadLines(() => file.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8).ToArray();
```

I hope to be helpful

Comment: that defeats the purpose of the user, that will return all lines in an array, is exactly the same as `File.ReadAllLines` but with a lot of overhead, the user wants to read it line by line to process it and not have all the file on memory.

Comment: @Gusman It will not, it will return one line at a time from the stream. It returns an IEnumerable not an array. (Original code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13312954/468973)

Comment: so I return `yield return line` and It could be enumerate and It could be run with `ToArray`

Comment: Ok, I read it wrong, sorry. Anyway an streamreader would be a lot more easy and the default way