# Write .csv data from stream to IList<string>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, filestream

i want to copy the data of an uploaded file to an IList object. The uploaded file is .csv-data.

My code looks like this:

```cs
        public void FileToIList(IFormFile importFile)
        {
            if (importFile != null)
            {
                //var path = Path.Combine(wwwrootDiectory, DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(importFile.FileName));
                //IList<string> = importFile.OpenReadStream().Read() <= does not work
        }
```

But I don't want to save the content of the importFile in a temporary data. I want to write the content in directly way into a IList object. Is it possible?

After this lines I don't know further.
Do you have a solution or maybe a idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file name, you can use [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_) to get an array (not a list) of all the lines in the file.

If you really have to have a list, or you only have access to a stream, you can use the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13312954).

Comment: hey @gnud, thank you for your response. I have no filepath, because i get the data from MVC-View and want to store it in a IList to work futher with the data-content. I want to avoid to store the data in a server directory.

Comment: Did you try the approach in the other answer I linked? There's a simple method there to read a stream once line-by-line and yield each line into an enumerable. It should be easy to append to a list instead.